# How to allow third party cookies in Safari 11.0.3 (13604.5.6)

Tags: safari

I cannot find a way to allow third party cookies in Safari 11.0.3 (13604.5.6). Previous versions had a 'always allow' in privacy tab like the picture below

[image]

While(13604.5.6)has this privacy tab:

[image]

Comment: Unticking the "Prevent cross-site tracking" is what enables the use of third-party cookies.

Comment: Hmm I guess you are right. This fixes my issue. But isn't this for other things except third party cookies?

Comment: No, it isn't. "Tracking" in this context refers solely to third-party cookies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unticking the "Prevent cross-site tracking" is what enables the use of third-party cookies.

"Tracking" in this context refers solely to third-party cookies.

Comment: Is checking the box equivalent to "current website only" or "websites I visit"?